# matrix profile distance measure characterization

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-mining, distance

If there are various types of distances measures for time series, such as Euclidean, DTW, and shape-based ones, how can we characterize the matrix profile distance measure? Profiling one?

Comment: The Matrix Profile uses the z-normalized Euclidean Distance. However, there is a (slower) version that use DTW.

Comment: @EamonnKeogh https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/111277/multi-dimensional-time-series-and-matrix-profile-method